# Trigger not finding table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, triggers

I'm learning about and how to use SQL triggers. I'm building a test database that isn't part of my classes so I can practice.

The problem is I'm getting

> The object 'dbo.StudentInfo' does not exist or is invalid for this
>   operation

1) I have permissions, I'm the administrator.

2) I'm absolutely positive I'm in the correct database.

3) I have tried `dbo.StudentInfo`, `StudentInfo`, `[dbo.StudentInfo]` (which I know is wrong anyway) and `[dbo].[StudentInfo]`, and all of them give me the same error.

What else could be wrong? What other information would you need to help?

```
Use Test3
GO
CREATE TRIGGER tr_high_date 
    ON  [dbo].[StudentInfo]
    FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for trigger here

END
GO
```

Table Information:

```
USE [test3]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[StudentInfo]    Script Date: 9/22/2015 9:39:53 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentInfo](
    [StudentID] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [NickName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [char](10) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [DateAdded] [date] NOT NULL,
    [DateExpectedGraduation] [date] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[StudentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Comment: What happens if you try SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StudentInfo] in the same query window? Your code works fine here so the object either does not exist, you're on the wrong database or don't have permissions.

Comment: I get the same error Invalid ObjectName, but it still pulls back information. It doesn't make sense to me though because i have refreshed the database. do I have to open and close SQL Server for it to work or is there a way to quickly refresh everything?

Comment: where do you get that eror?

Comment: When do you get this error? When you try to execute the create trigger code?

Comment: In styling a trigger code. JBond helped Answer it. Turns out the Database hadn't really refreshed itself when I refreshed it. Twice.

Comment: And if JBond wants to answer with "Try turning off and turning it on again, I will be very happy. And mark this question as answered.

Comment: Turning it off and back on???? What does that mean??? Are you saying it was just an intellisense issue? You don't need to restart SSMS for that, just refresh the local cache. ctrl + shift + r

Comment: And since you are learning triggers you need to make sure you do not have scalar variables in the body of your triggers. The code needs to be set based and always assume there are multiple rows in inserted or deleted.

Comment: It's ok. It wasn't really an answer. Intellisense wouldn't have thrown a runtime or compile exception. So i'm assuming it wasn't actually an exception and you were referring to the red squiggly lines in the intellisense in SQL manageent studio by any change? In which case, do what @SeanLange mentioned.

Comment: Sean Lange, Yes it was Intellisense Issue, thanks, I was wondering how to do that.

@SeanLange, Interesting, do you mind if we have a private chat so we don't bug up this page? there are a couple of questions i have regarding how to do what I want to do and some more questions now based on your scalar Variable comment

JBond yeah, it was intellisense. Thanks!

Comment: @Aツ I'm trying to work with creating Triggers for "Subquery Contained more than 1 value" like Sean Lange suggested and you mentioned on the other page but no one has really helped with yet. The only way I can think of doing it is a systematic while Less than RowCount, Select Top 1 @ Index loop. This seems like it will be a huge burden on the system. What could/should I look for to simplify things?

Comment: your other question died or am i too tired to find it?

Comment: Nah, I killed it. I only have so much reputation, and if I lost any more I wouldn't be able to vote again. So @Aツ, could you help please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the correct database? Maybe you're in the master database and your tables are in a different database or vice versa.